# Generic "Killed" error in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am working on a CRON job that invokes a PHP script which does a lot of database work with loops.

It executes properly when I limit the data set, but when I run it against the full data set, the script errors out with a message:

```
Killed
```

set_time_limit is (0) and memory_limit is (-1)

Here is the code section where it consistently dies:

```
echo "I'm in _getMemberDemographicAttrs\n";
if (! empty ( $member_id )) {
    $query .= ' AND member_id = ' . $member_id;
}

$result = mysql_query ( $query, $this->_db );
if ($result) {
    while ( $rule = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $result ) ) {
        $rules [] = $rule;
    }
    if (! empty ( $rules )) {
        mysql_free_result ( $result );
        echo "I'm leaving _getMemberDemographicAttrs\n";
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
I'm in _getMemberDemographicAttrs<br/>
I'm leaving _getMemberDemographicAttrs<br/>
I'm in _getMemberDemographicAttrs<br/>
I'm leaving _getMemberDemographicAttrs<br/>
I'm in _getMemberDemographicAttrs<br/>
Killed
```

I've never seen this generic `Killed` error message and I'm wondering what is causing it to be killed?

Comment: I just got this error on PHP 7.4, and the culprit was an anonymous class which overrides a method. I added a parameter to the base method in the parent class, but forgot the parameter in the anonymous child class. For some reason PHP did not parse this correctly and hogged memory until the OOM killer `Killed` the process. Adding the missing param to the anon class fixed the issue. Sounds like a bug in PHP to be honest.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You might be triggering the Linux out-of-memory (OOM) killer. Check `dmesg` for messages about it. It says which process was killed when this happens.

Comment: Thanks for this. I found that Linux was killing the process. I resolved it by reducing the memory limit for PHP in the script, which allowed PHP to manage its memory differently and avoid the crash.

Comment: For me, the problem was resolved by upgrading from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7. Obviously it depends on many factors but PHP 7 works more efficient so it is worth checking out.

Comment: For me, I'm running PHP7 and I've got killed, even though I've 3GB free ram! and PHP memory limit was set to -1, I'm trying to @Fuser97381 solution.

Answer (score 18):

**Simple way to reproduce this `Killed` error:**

I was able to reproduce this error on `Ubuntu 12.10` with `PHP 5.3.10`.

Create a PHP script called `m.php` and save it:

```
<?php
    function repeat(){
       repeat();
    }
    repeat();
?>
```

Run it:

```
el@apollo:~/foo$ php m.php
Killed
```

The program takes 100% CPU for about 15 seconds then halts with the `Killed` message.  Look at `dmesg | grep php` and there are clues:

```
el@apollo:~/foo$ dmesg | grep php
[2387779.707894] Out of memory: Kill process 2114 (php) score 868 or 
sacrifice child
```

So in my case, the PHP program halted and printed "Killed" because it ran out of memory due to an infinite loop.

**Solutions:**

1. Increase the amount of RAM available or amount of memory available to this PHP program.
2. Break down the problem into smaller chunks that operate sequentially.
3. Rewrite the program so it has smaller memory requirements or doesn't go so deep with recursion.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on CloudLinux, PHP 7.1, it occurred when 2 processes were reading and writing to the same file without locks.