# Symfony2 command line app is "Killed" after a few minutes

Tags: command-line, symfony

I have a Symfony2 command line app that I've built.  It fetches a ton of data from a web service to pre-cache.  I'm running into a problem where after about 5 minutes the app is "Killed".

I run the command:

```
php app/console FTW:loadAuctionHouse
```

My application outputs its steps while running, and just outputs "Killed" all of a sudden after a few minutes.
So... question:  Is there a built in time limit to the command line apps?  Or is there something "funky" going on?  Can someone explain why this could happen?

Comment: Could you describe the environment you run your script on? It looks like the problem is not in PHP/Symfony. I.e. my hosting provider automatically kills long running processes.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.4 server. My own machine, so the process isn't being killed automatically. I have other PHP batch apps running outside of Symfony that have run, on occasion, for hours without issue.

Comment: What does `php -i| grep max_execution_time` return on your system?

Comment: `php -i | grep max_execution_time` results in 
`max_execution_time => 0 => 0`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic "Killed" error in PHP CRON job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952868/generic-killed-error-in-php-cron-job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that this issue was caused by PHP itself.  I've since upgraded the OS on my server (which in turn upgraded the PHP version) and this issue has been fixed.  I did further investigation and found that this issue was corrected in php 5.3

Answer (score 1):

As every php application (cli as well as apache or anything else) there is a execution time limit. Add

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

to your command line tool to prevent this. **CAUTION:** This will result in a script that runs till infinity if caught in an endless loop or some recursion loop. While this solution is better than increasing the script execution time in your php.ini, it should be done only when really neccessary.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this didn't change anything for me :( it still stops with "Killed" with the time limit specified in the code.

Comment: Would you mind trying to change the execution time etc. in the php.ini for testing purpose? See http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time for information.

Comment: My cli php.ini had the execution time set to 600, when I changed this to 0 and ran my app... it still responds with "Killed" after about 9 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Doctrine in your script ?

In this case, that could be a memory issue; every time you load an Entity, the EntityManager keeps a reference, you need to detach/clear/flush (depends on your needs) your Entities.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html

(Link updated)

Comment: Yes, using doctrine; I will give this a try.  In the end this script performs about 100k insert statements, so your suggestion just might be the answer I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: I am also having this problem. I have used flush after one for loop execution. What else can I do?

Comment: The above answer of LayMain is correct. It was memory issue.. I added more flush and it works great...

Comment: @Chris You should mark your question as answered if it was the solution

Comment: @Laymain I haven't had an opportunity to refactor this part of the project.  I ended up doing this as a pure PHP app (no framework) since I was having issues with Symfony and Doctrine.  Once I go back and fix I'll mark the question answered if it solved my problem.  Thanks again for your help!