# My long running laravel 4 command keeps being killed

Tags: php, laravel, command, kill-process

I have a laravel 4 web project that implements a laravel command.

When running in the development homestead vm, it runs to completion (about 40 seconds total time).

However when running it on the production server, it quits with a 'killed' output on the command line.

At first i thought it was the max_execution_time in cli php.ini, so I set it to 0 (for unlimited time).

How can I find out what is killing my command?

I run it on ssh terminal using the standard artisan invokation:

php artisan commandarea:commandname

Does laravel 4 have a command time limit somewhere?

The vps is a Ubuntu 4.10 machine with mysql, nginx and php-fpm

Comment: cli php by default has no execution time limit. perhaps it's something else, like the system OOM monitor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952868/generic-killed-error-in-php-script

Comment: thanks @RichardChristensen, yes dmesg does indeed show linux has killed my script due to out of memory....  2999.882248] Out of memory: Kill process 7819 (php) score 554 or sacrifice child
[ 2999.882338] Killed process 7819 (php) total-vm:445160kB, anon-rss:286012kB, file-rss:0kB

Comment: @RichardChristensen, if you put your link as the answer (basically telling me to do dmesg). I will credit you with the answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, firstly, thank you everyone who has pointed me in the right direction regarding PHP and laravel memory usage tracking.

I have answered my own question hoping that it will benefit laravel devs in the future, as my solution was hard to find.

After typing 'dmesg' to show system messages. I found that the php script was being killed by Linux.

So, I added memory logging calls into my script before and after each of the key areas of my script:

```
Log::Info('Memory now at: ' . memory_get_peak_usage());
```

Then I ran the script while watching the log output and also the output of the 'top' command.

I found that even though my methods were ending and the variables were going out of scope, the memory was not being freed.

Things that I tried, that **DIDNT** make any difference in my case:

1. unset($varname) on variables after I have finished with them - hoping to get GC to kick off
2. adding gc_enable() at beginning of script and then adding gc_collect_cycle() calls after a significant number of vars are unset.
3. Disabling mysql transactions - thinking maybe that is memory intensive - it wasnt.

Now, the odd thing was that none of the above made any difference. My script was still using 150mb or ram by time it killed!

The solution that actually worked:

Now this is definitely a laravel specific solution.
But my scripts purpose is basically to parse a large xml feed and then insert thousands of rows into mysql using Elequent ORM.

It turns out that Laravel creates logging information and objects to help you see the query performance.

By turning this off with the following 'magic' call, I got my script down from 150mb to around 20mb!

This is the 'magic;' call:

```
DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
```

I can tell you by the time I found this call, I was grasping at straws ;-(

Comment: Just a note for anyone reading this in morning times: since [Laravel version 4.2](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#query-logging) the DB QueryLog is disabled by default. Also, since [Laravel version 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database) there is no queryLog and instead there is a DB::listen method you might use, and might need to disable if you're having memory issues with large data sets.

Answer (score 4):

A process may be killed for several reasons:

**Out of Memory**

There are two ways to trigger this error: Exceed the amount of memory allocated to PHP script in php.ini, or exceed the available system memory. Check the PHP error log and php.ini file to rule out the first possibility, and use dmesg output to check for the second possibility.

**Exceeded the execution time-out limit**

In your post you indicate that you disabled the timeout via the `max_execution_time` setting, but I have included it here for completeness. Be sure that the setting in php.ini is correct and (for those using a web server instead of a CLI script) restart the web server to ensure that the new configuration is active.

**An error in the stack**

If your script is error-free and not encountering either of the above errors, ensure that your system is running as expected. When using a web server, restart the web server software. Check the error logs for unexpected output, and stop or upgrade related daemons and needed.

Comment: Yeah, the "killed" that I was experiencing was from the Linux Kernel shutting it down after PHP exhausted all of the available RAM. I watched `top` as the script ran to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue on a Laravel/Spark project.  just wanted to share if others have this issue.

Try a refresh/restart of your dev server if running Vagrant or Ubuntu before more aggressive approaches.

I accidentally ran install of dependency packages on a Vagrant server.  I also removed and replaced a mirrored folder repeatedly during install errors.  My error was on Laravel/Spark 4.~.  I was able to run migrations on other projects; I was getting 'killed' very quickly, 300ms timeframe, on a particular project for nearly all commands.  Reading other users, I was dreading trying to find the issue or corruption.  In my case, a quick Vagrant reload did the trick.  killed issue was resolved.