# My Etherscan API script stopped working after 3 days of flawless operation, and simply printed "Killed" as its final message, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, vps, etherscan

I built a script to interface with the Etherscan API and track crypto addresses, everything was going good and whenever a watched address sent a transfer I would receive an email update. It's been operating perfectly with no issues over the last 3 days.

Almost 24 hours ago, the script stopped working, and instead of attempting to retry accessing the etherscan webpage after a wait period of 5 seconds, like I have programmed it to, it simply printed "killed" as its last words. I didnt code it to ever print "Killed". I have checked with the server provider and I have plenty of funds in my account and there are no issues that I can see.

Does anyone know why it would have printed "Killed" and stopped working?

If the error is stemming from a memory error, as what seems to be the case in the thread that davis linked, do I need to increase the memory of the server that I am renting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic "Killed" error in PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952868/generic-killed-error-in-php-script)

Comment: Hi @davisHerring, I'm not sure to be honest. The script is coded in python, which I was under the impression did things like memory managment all under the hood, so It would be very difficult to write a script that would run it dry of memory. would it be sensible to write a line of code instructing the script to print how much memory is being used after each loop, and then if it crashes again in a few days time I could check what the final memory usage was before the crash?

Comment: It’s most certainly possible to leak memory in a garbage-collected language—you just have to build a structure through which it is possible to *reach* an ever-increasing number of objects.  You could try printing memory usage, but that’s surprisingly difficult to measure yourself; you might start with the kernel’s log to confirm that it was the OOM killer, but “Killed” is already very strong evidence of that.

Comment: okay, i've added a line of code that prints the current memory usage of the program after every loop, so next time it crashes I can just check if the memory useage was higher than my servers memory allocation